# MySQL - How to query multiple tables and put results in xls?

Tags: php, mysql, xls, multiple-tables

I have two tables and I must select some records and put it in xls by using PHP script.

I'm try different query but not working.

On JOD_users table i need to select id, name, username, email and on JOD_user_profiles i need to select profile_key and profile_value but the profile_value are in the same column (this is my problem).

[image: tables structure]

How can I have the result in a single row?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the profile_value are in the same column? what do you mean?

Comment: To make query in multiple table you have use JOIN for mapping and export the result data in csv or excel format.

Comment: @user3421040 Please do not use images for content that is basically text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a INNER JOIN query like this:

`SELECT user.*, profile.* FROM JOD_users user INNER JOIN JOD_user_profile profile ON user.id = profile.user_id`

Answer (score -1):

I Solved by make this query inside my foreach :

select JOD_user_profiles.* 
          from JOD_user_profiles 
          where JOD_user_profiles.user_id =".$row->id." and JOD_user_profiles.profile_key like 'profile5.%'

Thanks a lot.